# How to shade an area in ggplot mixing geom_rect and geom_line?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Consider this data:

```
shade <- structure(list(from = structure(c(6940, 7670, 8766, 13879, 14610, 
15340), class = "Date"), to = structure(c(6940, 7670, 10227, 
13879, 14610, 17897), class = "Date")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I am trying to shade an area in ggplot with `shade`. The other part of the data is:

```
df <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(4383, 4748, 5113, 5479, 5844, 
6209, 6574, 6940, 7305, 7670, 8035, 8401, 8766, 9131, 9496, 9862, 
10227, 10592, 10957, 11323, 11688, 12053, 12418, 12784, 13149, 
13514, 13879, 14245, 14610, 14975, 15340, 15706, 16071, 16436, 
16801, 17167, 17532, 17897), class = "Date"), growth = c(0.0623150839421278, 
-0.0118611051533168, -0.0664501162049262, -0.087782956704693, 
-0.129496959622578, -0.18594460634209, -0.188214164298442, -0.172238123190157, 
-0.94277027404306, -0.0834575040012719, -0.0883082379839397, 
-0.101106281706148, -0.0371396056259545, -0.011174839245335, 
0.0182311778775262, 0.0549337165151567, 0.35326560836822, 0.320551702135409, 
0.295635261636084, 0.201819487872301, 0.045320365597334, 0.036634868496078, 
0.000464348739324549, -0.0302907006607054, -0.0615712296201636, 
-0.0850991148284894, -0.0819342537954828, -0.0874010742126909, 
-0.0688419496282826, -0.086814819317242, -0.0567750186957099, 
-0.0333039095763059, -0.00719293166024748, 0.0166361057943032, 
0.0707141351711211, 0.133846612601381, 0.156206411946355, 0.329862325903626
)), row.names = 23:60, class = "data.frame")
```

This is what I've tried, but it ignores rows that have the same values in `shade$from` and `shade$to`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)) +
  geom_line(data = df,  aes(x = Date, y = growth))
```

I guess a mix of `geom_rect` and `geom_line` from `ggplot` would work.

Comment: Can you describe or a provide a sketch what you want the final plot to look like?

Comment: I think you could do something like this ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y = growth)) +
 geom_area( fill = "lightblue",   color="blue", linetype="dashed", size=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add an `geom_vline` for the cases where your shaded areas are just vertical lines:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

ggplot() +
  geom_vline(data = dplyr::filter(shade, from == to), aes(xintercept = from)) +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf)) +
  geom_line(data = df,  aes(x = Date, y = growth))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Two options with or without a legend:

For a legend: add a factor to the shade data frame;

Use colour aesthetic as well as fill to manage the dates which are the same.

I suspect you cannot fill an area with no width.

You do not need to add additional geoms using this approach:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)

shade$area <- letters[1:nrow(shade)]

p1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf, colour = area, fill = area)) +
  geom_line(data = df,  aes(x = Date, y = growth))+
  ggtitle("Shade each area identifiable with legend")


p2 <- ggplot() +
  geom_rect(data = shade, aes(xmin = from, xmax = to, ymin = -Inf, ymax = Inf), colour = "gray50", fill = "gray50") +
  geom_line(data = df,  aes(x = Date, y = growth))+
  ggtitle("Shade uniform colour, without legend")


p1/p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-26 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>